# Trace context propagation in grpc java service

Tags: instrumentation, grpc-java, open-telemetry, telemetry

I have a core java based service which communicates with another .NET service through grpc calls. The java service receives grpc requests from the .NET service and it will process the request and will send back a grpc response.

I have instrumented the java service using the opentelemetry java agent and the .NET service is instrumented manually.
In the production setup, both these services will be part of a single application . So I want to setup proper context propagation between these services. I want to be able to see the traces of the java service aligned with that of the .NET service.

I tried by creating a `TextMapPropagator` and extracting the trace context from the metadata headers using a `TextMapGetter` and creating spans with parent as the extracted context. But I got the value as null from the extracted context.

```
public class ServerHeadInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor
{
private final Tracer tracer = GlobalOpenTelemetry.getTracer("my-tracer);

public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call, Metadata headers, ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next)
    {

TextMapPropagator propagator = GlobalOpenTelemetry.getPropagators().getTextMapPropagator();

Context extractedContext = propagator.extract(Context.current(), headers, new TextMapGetter<Metadata>()
        {
            @Override
            public Iterable<String> keys(Metadata carrier)
            {
                return carrier.keys();

            }


            @Nullable
            @Override
            public String get(@Nullable Metadata carrier, String key)
            {
                Metadata.Key<String> traceParent = Metadata.Key.of(key, Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER);
                String value = carrier.get(traceParent);
                System.out.println("VALUE :" + value);
                return value;
            }
        });

Span span = tracer.spanBuilder("my-span).setSpanKind(SpanKind.CONSUMER).setParent(extractedContext).startSpan;

try(Scope scope =span.makeCurrent()
{ 

return new ForwardingServerCallListener.SimpleForwardingServerCallListener<ReqT>(next.startCall(call, headers)) {};

}
finally
{
span.end()
}
```

How can I extract the trace context from an incoming grpc request and create spans from that context ?

Does the opentelemetry java agent offer any automatic functionality for that ?

There are multiple grpc requests coming to the java service from the .NET service, so is it possible to handle all those by extracting trace contexts from each request and creating spans from that context so that the traces will align properly?

NOTE : I use Grafana tempo as the traces exporter.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I extract the trace context from an incoming grpc request and create spans from that context ?

I think the solution you described using the propagator to extract the span context is correct. But by default `GlobalOpenTelemetry.getPropagators().getTextMapPropagator()` is noop propagator, so if you didn't configure it you get nothing out of it. You have to use a real propagator instance. OpenTelemetry supports a few built in propagators, e.g. w3c, see [here](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/specs/otel/context/api-propagators/#propagators-distribution)